# Cleanup fails after failed merge - SVN 1.7.x

Tags: svn, tortoise-svn

I was attempting to merge a branch back into trunk, however one of the files involved in the merge was opened and locked by another program, so the merge operation failed.

Due to the failed merge, SVN reported that a cleanup was required for any operations, but trying a cleanup resulted in an error along the lines of:

```
Cleanup failed to process the following paths: C:\Working\Copy 
Can't open file 'C:\Users\Me\AppData\Local\Temp\svn-<hex value>'. 
The system cannot find the file specified.
```

The repository is 14GB, so simply deleting the entire working copy and checking out again is not desirable. Plus I had local changes which would have been tricky to track down without the ability to use SVN to inspect them.

As this is a centralized working copy db (single .svn in the working copy root), there is no option to operate on individual sub-folders to avoid operating on the entire repository.

TortoiseSVN 1.7.10 on Windows 7 x64

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my case, there were two entries in the WORK_QUEUE table in the .svn/wc.db file in my working copy (which referred to the missing file in the temp directory as a result of the failed merge).

I used SQLite Expert Personal to open wc.db and delete those two rows from WORK_QUEUE.

I had to try this a couple of times, probably due to using the TortoiseSVN explorer shell extension, I needed to restart explorer after deleting the rows from wc.db, and before attempting an SVN Cleanup.

SVN Cleanup was successful after the invalid rows were deleted and explorer was restarted.